# Textbox как считать значение

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-webforms, webforms

Есть вебформа с текстбоксом и кнопкой. Текст бокс заполняю так :

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(GlobalVariable.connectionString))
        {
            con.Open();
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
            {
                cmd.Connection = con;

                cmd.CommandText = "select * from lalala";
                dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                if (dr.Read())
                {
                    depotValue18.Text = dr["value18"].ToString();
                }
                dr.Close();
            }
        }
       btn_save.Click += btn_save_Click;
    }
```

Сама кнопка:

```
void btn_save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Write("<script>window.alert('ku-ku" + depotValue18.Text + "');</script>");

    //using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(GlobalVariable.connectionString))
    //{
    //    con.Open();
    //    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
    //    {
    //        cmd.Connection = con;
    //        cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE lalal SET value18 = "+ depotValue18.Text +" WHERE code = 'lalala'";
    //        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    //    }
    //}
}
```

При нажатии я получаю текст, не тот который ввел снова, а тот который подтянулся во время выполнения `Page_Load`. Например во время загрузки страницы `depotValue18` стал равен 21, я изменяю его на 15 и нажимаю кнопку, то `alert` отобразит 21. Почему так? Логически я понимаю, похоже что при нажатии снова отрабатывает `Page_Load` а уже потом код кнопки, или нет? Как быть?

Comment: Продиагностируйте порядок выполнения кода в обоих методах

Comment: @МстиславПавлов вы считаете что то не так? Или просто совет?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно проверить - первый раз страница загружается или нет. Прочитайте про свойство [IsPostBack](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.web.ui.page.ispostback(v=vs.110).aspx)